# Prolog task with multiple condition

Tags: prolog

```
(e(),[],X).
(m(X,D),[X|Xs],X) :- (D,Xs, X).
(n(X,D),[X|Xs],Y) :- Y \= X, (D, Xs, Y).

?- (Desc,[1,2],2).
```

Can someone explain me please how we normally do these type of tasks?

Desc = n(1,m(2,e()) - that is the answer. But i don't understand, how we got it.

Comment: Is this a code obfuscation contest? Should contain meaningful predicate names, meaningful variable names, and meaningful comments to explain the code's intent when unclear.

Comment: Using a debugger would he you understand "how we got it".  Exactly what "it" is may still remain a mystery.